# React Native - AsyncStorage Items to Flatlist

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous

I'm trying to display/store a list of items in my flatlist, but the problem is when I save an item and load that item in a different screen it is in a kind of repetition(look for the screen shot). And when I try to add different item, this new item will replace the previous item with the same kind of repetition. What I'm targeting is to have a list.

[List_ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcxHe.png)

Here is my code

AddModal.js

```
export default class AddModal extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          modalVisible: props.modalVisible,
          id: null,
          count: 0,
          price: null
        };
    }

    state = {
        text: '',
    }

    save = () => {
        const { text } = this.state;
        let myArray = {
            text, text
        }
        AsyncStorage.setItem('myArray', JSON.stringify(myArray));
        alert(text + 'saved');
    }

    onChange = (text) => {
        this.setState({ text });
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({
          modalVisible: nextProps.modalVisible,
            id: nextProps.id,
            price: nextProps.price
        })
    }

    render() {
      console.log('inside AppModal', this.state.modalVisible);
        return (
                <View>
                    <TextInput style = { styles.input }
                        keyboardType = "numeric"
                        onChangeText = { this.onChange }
                        value = { this.state.text }       //Item **
                     >
                     </TextInput>
                </View>

                <View}>
                     <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress = {() => { this.props.setModalVisible(false) }}
                                    >
                           <Text style = { styles.buttonText }>Cancel</Text>
                     </TouchableOpacity>

                     <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress = { this.save }>
                           <Text style = { styles.buttonText }>Send</Text>
                     </TouchableOpacity>
                 </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Settlment.js

```
import Details from '../Menus/Details';
const key = '@MyApp:key';
export default class Settlement extends React.Component {
    state = {
        text: '',
        storedValue: '',
        myArray: ''
    }

      componentWillMount() {
        //this.onLoad();
        AsyncStorage.getItem('myArray')
        .then(text => this.setState({ text }));
    }

    showData = async() => {
        let myArray = await AsyncStorage.getItem('myArray');
        let d = JSON.parse(myArray);
        this.setState({ myArray : myArray });
    }

  render() {
      const { myArray, text } = this.state;
    return (
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress = {this.showData}>
                <Text>Load Data</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <FlatList data = { this.state.myArray }
                renderItem = {({ item }) => 
                    <Text>{myArray}</Text>
                }
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            >
            </FlatList>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to read through this much logic to answer your question. But I would bet that the cause is because you are adding references to some object to your flat list instead of primitive values. Therefore, when you change one val you change them all.

Comment: Should I use other component? like mergeItem, sir? Sorry, I'am very new to react native.

Answer (score 0):

What I see here:

```
      const { text } = this.state;
    let myArray = {
        text, text
    }
    AsyncStorage.setItem('myArray', JSON.stringify(myArray));
    alert(text + 'saved');
```

is an object called myArray, and nothing is being added to it. It's being defined and then assigned a value.

Maybe you could declare your array elsewhere like in the constructor (as an array, not an object, using `myArray = []`) and then use `myArray.push(text)` or if you want an array containing objects you can push object using `myArray.push({ yourKeyName: text })`. Also, it seems like the object you're storing in AsyncStorage is being replaced and not added to. But I'm not sure why you're getting multiple list items instead of just one.

PS - Where you're declaring state looks a bit off. I usually see it like this:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { 
        text: '',
        storedValue: '',
        myArray: '',
    };
}
```